eslint-plugin-tailwindcss configuration not working
I'm having trouble putting the tailwind css plugin for eslint to work... I'm using sveltekit, not sure if that is relevant
I've tried everything I know and could find online...
the eslint.config.js contains a console log just to show that the tailwind css object is being properly added to the settings object
here is the eslint.config.js:
import eslint from '@eslint/js';
import prettier from 'eslint-config-prettier';
import svelte from 'eslint-plugin-svelte';
import globals from 'globals';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';
import tailwindcss from 'eslint-plugin-tailwindcss';

const test = tseslint.config(
    eslint.configs.recommended,
    ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
    ...svelte.configs['flat/recommended'],
    ...tailwindcss.configs['flat/recommended'],
    prettier,
    ...svelte.configs['flat/prettier'],
    {
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser,
                ...globals.node
            }
        }
    },
    {
        files: ['**/*.svelte', '**/*.js', '**/*.ts'],
        languageOptions: {
            parserOptions: {
                parser: tseslint.parser
            }
        }
    },
    {
        ignores: ['build/', '.svelte-kit/', 'dist/']
    },
);

console.log(test);

export default test;

here is the package.json if it's needed:
{
    "name": "sveltekit-ssg-demo-app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --write ./src && eslint ./src --fix",
        "format": "prettier --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^3.0.5",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.7.1",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.1.2",
        "@types/eslint": "^9.6.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
        "eslint": "^9.12.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.44.1",
        "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.17.5",
        "@eslint/js": "^9.12.0",
        "globals": "^15.11.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.47",
        "prettier": "^3.3.3",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.2.7",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.6.8",
        "svelte": "^4.2.19",
        "svelte-check": "^4.0.5",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.14",
        "typescript": "^5.6.3",
        "typescript-eslint": "^8.9.0",
        "vite": "^5.4.9"
    },
    "type": "module"
}

I have the file src/routes/+page.svelte
<div class="flex grid">
  <p>test</p>
</div>

it should trigger the no-contradicting-classname rule from eslint-plugin-tailwindcss because of this <div class="flex grid"> but nothing happens
I've ran the eslint ./src command with the --debug flag (eslint ./src --debug) and verified that the file in question is being checked and that both eslint-plugin-svelte configs are mentioned in the logs (lines 11 and 14 of the eslint.config.js file ...svelte.configs['flat/recommended'], ...svelte.configs['flat/prettier']) but the ...tailwindcss.configs['flat/recommended'] never appears
here are the eslint-plugin-svelte configs I mentioned appear in the logs when running esling with the --bebug flag:
  eslint:linter Apply the processor: { meta: { name: 'eslint-plugin-svelte', version: '2.44.1' }, supportsAutofix: true, preprocess: [Function: preprocess], postprocess: [Function: postprocess] } +0ms
  eslint:linter Apply the processor: { meta: { name: 'eslint-plugin-svelte', version: '2.44.1' }, supportsAutofix: true, preprocess: [Function: preprocess], postprocess: [Function: postprocess] } +0ms

tailwind is never mentioned in the logs, but it is on the config object (confirmed by the console log) does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
Thank you!
I've tried to add the eslint-plugin-tailwindcss config object to the eslint.config.js in multiple ways

There is the same problem with my program,but i can't fix it.

Yeah...after some more testing I concluded that the plugin is simply not compatible with svelte. I opened an issue in the plugin GitHub but no one answered, so I just removed the plugin from my project and moved on!

This answer does not answer the question.
